# C# coalescing operator with 3 possible return values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, operators, coalescing

Just reading up on the specs for this operator `??` as it takes the left side and, if null returns the value on the right side.

My question is, can I have it return 3 possible values instead?

Something like this:

```
int? y = null;
int z = 2;

int x = y ?? (z > 1 ? z : 0);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: what happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely - you could use `??` in the same way as any other binary operator, meaning that you could have any expression on its left and/or on its right.

For example, you could do something like this:

```
int? a = ...
int? b = ...
int? c = ...
int? d = ...
int? res = (condition_1 ? a : b) ?? (condition_2 ? c : d);
```

This expression will evaluate `(condition_1 ? a : b)` first, check if it's `null`, and then either use the non-null value as the result, or evaluate the right-hand side, and us it as the result.

You can also "chain" the null coalesce operators `??`, like this:

```
int? res =a ?? b ?? c ?? d;
```

Evaluation of this expression goes left to right.

Comment: I don't understand the chaining for this... how does that work.  Do you have to have `int?` with a question mark at the end of `int` in order for it to work that way?

Comment: @SolomonClosson `??` expression requires a nullable on its left-hand side, so in my example above `a`, `b`, and `c` must be `int?`; `d` could be `int?` or `int`. Chained expression is evaluated left-to-right - first, `a??b`, then `(a??b)??c`, then `((a??b)??c)??d`.

Comment: Curious, what if I wanted to do this to a `Dictionary<string, string>` in order to put default values in if a key is not found?  Would it be done like this:  `Dictionary<string?, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string?, string>();` and than would I be able to do this:  `string theKey = myDictionary["keyNotinDictionary"] ?? "Not Found";`??

Comment: @SolomonClosson No. First, `Dictionary<K,V>` is a reference type, i.e. it's already nullable, so you do not need `??`. Second, when a key is not there and you call `dict[...]`, `Dictionary` throws an exception. Unfortunately, you cannot do it in one line - the best you can do is two lines: `string res; string theValue = myDictionary.TryGetValue("keyNotinDictionary", out res) ? res : "Not Found";`

Answer (score 2):

The `??` is a binary operator, but the second operand (the right hand side) can be any expression you want (as long as it has a suitable return type to be coalesced with the first operand). So yes, the second operand can be `(z > 1 ? z : 0)`. That doesn't make the `??` have 3 possible return values.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Just wanted to check if this is a valid thought process here.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is perfectly legit as is.  You can also do something like:

```
int x = a ?? b ?? c;
```

Comment: But this wouldn't work if `a` and/or `b` are not nullable right?

Comment: Right. ?? is meant for nullable. But this is one method you could use to choose between three values.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it 's possible.
Try to compile and make some test you should verify by yourself.